# replace words with perl script reading from table (to anonymize names)

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am looking for a way to replace words in a large text with perl and would like to read the words from another file containing the substitutions. I know I can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh_in, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "No input: $!";
open my $fh_out, '>', $ARGV[1] or die "No output: $!";

while (<$fh_in>) 
{
    s/John/Jack/g;

    print $fh_out $_;
}
```

... and put any number of `s/Fred/Frank/g;` lines. 
Is it possible to refer to an external text file containing all the substitutions?  It's in order to anonymize Names in interviews.

I'm thinking of keeping a simple text file in the Format:

```
Name    Pseudonym   
John    Jack  
Fred    Frank  
etc.
```

(separated by tabs)
If there are better ways to do it I'd be thankful for suggestions. 
The original comes from an Excel database that has all the name substitutions in two columns but it's fairly easy to get that into a text file and I don't want to make it too complicated since I'm not very familiar with scripting and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file that contains the correspondances in a hash then do the substitution like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh_in, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "No input: $!";
open my $fh_out, '>', $ARGV[1] or die "No output: $!";

open my $fh_pseudo, '<', "path/to/pseudo" or die "unable to open pseudo: $!";
my %corres;
while (<$fh_pseudo>) {
    chomp;
    my ($name, $pseudo) = split /\t/, $_;
    $corres{$name} = $pseudo if $name && $pseudo;
}

while (my $line = <$fh_in>) {
    $line =~ s/\b$_\b/$corres{$_}/g for keys %corres;
    print $fh_out $line;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I'm getting an error though, saying: `Use of uninitialized value $corres{""} in substitution iterator at /Users/me/Library/Scripts/script.pl line 18, <$fh_in> line 3.` I'm running from the command line with `perl script.pl input.txt output.txt`

Comment: also I corrected in line 12 there seems to be an "s" missing in <$fh_peudo>

Comment: @jan: I've modified the script to take into account null name or pseudo. Also, you're right about missing `s`.

Comment: That works! Thanks so much.  Just one more question if I may: If I want to integrate that part into another script that already has a (rather complex) while-loop like this `while (<$fh_in>) { if` ... and then some other stuff ...  `print $fh_out $_; }` how would I combine them? I tried writing one `while` block after the other but that didn't do it.

Comment: @jan: The best way is to change `$_` by `$line` in the the whole while loop.

Comment: I figured it out.  —  Just out of curiosity, since I'm not very used to voting behavior here on SO, aside from accepting your answer I also upvoted it, but then someone downvoted right away so it's back to 0.  Should I not have upvoted?  What is considered an answer worthy of a vote?  Whomever downvoted also didn't leave any comment explaining why ...

Comment: @jan: There're no real rules for up/down voting. It's up to you, If the answer seems usefull for you, upvote it, if it seems totaly wrong, downvote. Some people never gives reason for downvoting, here, my answer and the other one have been downvoting without any reason, c'est la vie.

Comment: Nonetheless it's weird why someone would do that?  Even the other answer is useful too, so I upvoted too, but then it got a downvote.  Well at least now you got another upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you read all the contents of the file you will perform the substitutions in memory before to make the substitutions.

Also you should be careful to not substitute a particular substring. If you have your Input file: "Hello Fred". And in the substitution list "Fred Frank" and "Frank Frankstein" you will end up with "Hello Frankstein"...

I put the substitution list under the **DATA** section, to make it self contained.

```
use strict;                                                                      
use warnings;                                                                    
use utf8;                                                                        
use IO::All;                                                                        

my %list;                                                                        

die "File not found or can't be read\n"                                          
unless $ARGV[0] && -e $ARGV[0] && -r $ARGV[0];                                 

die "Need an output file name\n" unless $ARGV[1];                                
my $output = $ARGV[1];                                                           

while (<DATA>) {                                                                 
    my ( $name, $nick ) = m/(\w+)\t(\w+)$/;                                      
    next unless $name && $nick;                                                  
    $list{$name} = $nick;                                                        
}                                                                                   

my $contents = io->file($ARGV[0])->slurp;                                           

for my $name ( keys %list ) {                                                    
    $contents =~ s/\b$name\b/$list{$name}/g;                                         
}                                                                                

$contents > io($output);                                                         

__DATA__                                                                         

John    Jack                                                                     
Fred    Frank
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  There are two reasons, why I prefer to have the DATA in a separate file. (a) this is part of a larger setup in which two or three different scripts that already do other replacements should as a last step do the anonymizations and they all need the same replacement data, and (b) new names will continuously be added to the file, and I'd rather not have to add them to all the scripts.  Would it be possible to adapt your answer to separate the DATA part from the script itself?

Comment: Yes it is, simply:

open(my $fh, "<", $nickname_file) and change while ( <DATA>) to while (<$fh>)